# Can I save only the name of the File class in java and hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Can I save `File` class as a `VARCHAR`, because I want to save a real file on a disc and save only filename in database as a `VARCHAR`. Maybe there is an annotation for example as

```java
@SaveAsString
private File file;
```

I'am using PostgreSQL and by default it saves `File` class as a `bytea` datatype.

Comment: Get the absolute path as string and use `varchar`

Comment: @g00se I want Hibernate to automatically map `File file` to the some column in the table, so I can automatically save, delete, update objects of the class

Comment: I don't know the inner workings of Hibernate. It could work maybe but Java just treats the file class as a way to manipulate paths. The sort of activity you mention comes via native calls ultimately. OTOH `File` *is* `Serializable` so you might be in with a chance